# Cakephp : Change location template folder

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I've searched through stackoverflow for my answer, but unfortunatly i didn't find the answer that i want.

What i'm trying to do is switch layout per page by the choices of the user. What I've done is there's a columns in the database, which save the location of the templates.

The problem is that in cakephp `$this->layout` automatically using the `Views/Layouts` folder.

But to locate the package of the templates I need to look into the folders content in my project. So what I've tried is using the

```
App::uses('Folder', 'Utility');
App::uses('File', 'Utility');
```

The problem with these utilities are they only check the folders in the `webroot`. I can't switch to the `Views/Layouts` directory.

So my problem is while `$this->layout` is using the directory `Views/Layout` and the utilities only search through the `webroot`- folder, they will never reach each other.

Database: 
|          Template               |
|          *TemplatePath*        |

Cakephp:

```
public function getTemplates() {
    $res = $this->getDirectory('Templates');
    if ($res):
        $templatedir = array();
        foreach ($res[0] as $directory):

            $res1 = $this->getDirectory('Templates' . DS . $directory);

            $templatedir[$directory] = $this->_optionTemplates($res1[1]);
        endforeach;

    endif;

    return $templatedir;
}

public function getDirectory($dirname) {
    $Folder = new Folder('/'.$dirname);

    $check = $Folder->inPath(WWW_ROOT . $dirname . DS, true);
    if (!$check):
        return false;
    endif;

    $dir = new Folder(WWW_ROOT . $dirname);
    return $dir->read();
}

private function _optionTemplates($directory) {
    $pattern = array(0 => '/.ctp/');
    if ($directory):
        $templatefiles = array();
        foreach ($directory as $file):
            $template = preg_replace($pattern, ' ', $file);
            $templatefiles[$template] = $template;
        endforeach;
        return $templatefiles;
    endif;
    return false;
}
```

Does someone has a suggestion for me how to solve this problem?

Either trying to switch the location of the `$this->layout` or switch the search location of the utilities will be fine. Other solution also welcome.

PS: sorry for my bad english.

Comment: what is the problem when layout files resides in `views/Layout` ?

Comment: I can't assign the layout per page than, because `$this->layout` use the folder `views/layout`. And I need somehow the locations of the custom-layouts to save to my database. I've tried to use the cakephp utilities, but they can't search through `view/layout` folder.

Comment: Folder `views/layout` may contain many layout with different names its not necessary to have named `default.ctp`.you may reference these layouts with `$this->layout` depending upon conditions.